# VBA Sumifs works without error, but nothing does nothing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which should for the IRS from the Instrument column summon all items> 0 in the Valuation column. However, the following code, works without error, but nothing in the indicated location paste nothing.

```
INSTRUMENT  WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA
IRS     15864,3029
IRS     2953,771801
CIRS    23751398,88
```

The following screen shows that such a condition exists and should give the attessment
[image]

My code :

```
Dim rTable As Range
Dim rCol As Range
Dim rCriteria As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim rCol_A As Range
With wbMe.Sheets("pochodne")
    WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA = "WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA"
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    Set rCol = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set rCol_A = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=INSTRUMENT, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not rCol Is Nothing And Not rCol_A Is Nothing Then
       .Range("T38").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rTable.Columns(rCol.Column), rTable.Columns(rCol.Column), ">0", rTable.Columns(rCol_A.Column), "IRS")
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Much like your other variation of this question, you never assign a value to `INSTRUMENT` so `rCol_A` will be nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for qeusiton followint and thanks @Rory

```
Set wbMe = ActiveWorkbook
IRS = "INSTRUMENT"
With wbMe.Sheets("pochodne")
    WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA = "WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA"
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    Set rCol = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set rCol1 = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=IRS, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not rCol Is Nothing Then
        .Range("T36").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rTable.Columns(rCol.Column), rTable.Columns(rCol.Column), "<0", rTable.Columns(rCol1.Column), "IRS")
    Else
        SumCriteria = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If
End With
```